# Duplicate row in CSV with D3.js

Tags: csv, d3.js

Here is my problem: I have a CSV file that have the following colums

- Item type (car, moto, bus,...)
- Owner
- City/State
- Number (how many cars/moto/bus a specific owner owns)

I want to make a dynamic bubble D3.js chart. Each bubble should represent an item and I want that the user can sort them by type, owner or state. I [found](http://projects.delimited.io/experiments/force-bubbles/) a script that is working well except that it takes each line from the CSV to make a bubble. I'm trying to find a way to "duplicate" the bubble when number < 1 but until now I didn't find...

What is your advice? Should I use D3.js to do that? jQuery? Other?

Here is the code:

> ```
>   d3.csv('data/test.csv', function (error, data) {
>     var width = 600, height = 600;
>     var fill = d3.scale.ordinal().range(['#827d92','#827354','#523536','#72856a','#2a3285'])
>     var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
>         .attr("width", width)
>         .attr("height", height);
>     _.each(data, function (elem) {
>       elem.radius = 5;
>       elem.x = _.random(0, width);
>       elem.y = _.random(0, height);
>     });
>     var padding = 2;
>     var maxRadius = d3.max(_.pluck(data, 'radius'));
>     function getCenters(vname, w, h) {
>       var nodes = [], c =[], result = {};
>       var v = _.uniq(_.pluck(data, vname));
>       var l = d3.layout.treemap().size([w, h]).ratio(1/1);
>       _.each(v, function (k, i) {
>         c.push({name: k, value: 1}); 
>       });
>       nodes = l.nodes({children: c})[0].children;
>       for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
>         result[nodes[i].name] = nodes[i];
>       }
>       return result;
>     }
>     var nodes = svg.selectAll("circle")
>       .data(data);
>     nodes.enter().append("circle")
>       .attr("class", "node")
>       .attr("cx", function (d) { return d.x; })
>       .attr("cy", function (d) { return d.y; })
>       .attr("r", 2)
>       .style("fill", function (d) { return fill(d.cat_int); })
>       .on("mouseover", function (d) { showPopover.call(this, d); })
>       .on("mouseout", function (d) { removePopovers(); })
>     nodes.transition().duration(1000)
>       .attr("r", function (d) { return d.radius; })
>     var force = d3.layout.force()
>       .charge(0)
>       .gravity(0)
>       .size([width, height])
>     draw('cat_int');
>     $( ".btn" ).click(function() {
>       draw(this.id);
>     });
>     function draw (varname) {
>       var foci = getCenters(varname, 600, 600);
>       force.on("tick", tick(foci, varname, .45));
>       labels(foci)
>       force.start();
>     }
>     function tick (foci, varname, k) {
>       return function (e) {
>         data.forEach(function(o, i) {
>           var f = foci[o[varname]];
>           o.y += ((f.y + (f.dy / 2)) - o.y) * k * e.alpha;
>           o.x += ((f.x + (f.dx / 2)) - o.x) * k * e.alpha;
>         });
>         nodes
>           .each(collide(.1))
>           .attr("cx", function (d) { return d.x; })
>           .attr("cy", function (d) { return d.y; });
>       }
>     }
>     function labels (foci) {
>       svg.selectAll(".label").remove();
>       svg.selectAll(".label")
>       .data(_.toArray(foci)).enter().append("text")
>       .attr("class", "label")
>       .text(function (d) { return d.name })
>       .attr("transform", function (d) {
>         return "translate(" + (d.x + (d.dx / 2)) + ", " + (d.y + 20) + ")";
>       });
>     }
>     function removePopovers () {
>       $('.popover').each(function() {
>         $(this).remove();
>       }); 
>     }
>     function showPopover (d) {
>       $(this).popover({
>         placement: 'auto top',
>         container: 'body',
>         trigger: 'manual',
>         html : true,
>         content: function() { 
>           return "Category: " + d.cat_int + "<br/> Owner: " + d.owner + "<br/>Sate: " + d.state; }
>       });
>       $(this).popover('show')
>     }
>     function collide(alpha) {
>       var quadtree = d3.geom.quadtree(data);
>       return function(d) {
>         var r = d.radius + maxRadius + padding,
>             nx1 = d.x - r,
>             nx2 = d.x + r,
>             ny1 = d.y - r,
>             ny2 = d.y + r;
>         quadtree.visit(function(quad, x1, y1, x2, y2) {
>           if (quad.point && (quad.point !== d)) {
>             var x = d.x - quad.point.x,
>                 y = d.y - quad.point.y,
>                 l = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y),
>                 r = d.radius + quad.point.radius + padding;
>             if (l < r) {
>               l = (l - r) / l * alpha;
>               d.x -= x *= l;
>               d.y -= y *= l;
>               quad.point.x += x;
>               quad.point.y += y;
>             }
>           }
>           return x1 > nx2 || x2 < nx1 || y1 > ny2 || y2 < ny1;
>         });
>       };
>     }
>   });
> ```

Comment: Well have you tried duplicating the lines in the CSV?

Comment: Yes I did that and it works, thanks!
But this solution is not optimal because I will receive periodically an updated version of the CSV and I'll have to modify it each time before uploading it. Of course this is doable but I would have preferred a 100% automated solution.

Comment: You could do the same thing programmatically -- duplicate the "rows".

Comment: Yeap. I just wrote a short Google Apps Script to duplicate the rows! Thanks for your help